# Float элемент в Firefox неправильно отображается

Tags: html, css, firefox, float

Как исправить неправильное отображение float элемента в фаерфоксе? Пример:

https://codepen.io/Ssivenkov/full/OJRwqvq

В хроме отображается нормально, а в фаерфоксе почему-то появляется пустое пространство

```
<div class="float-polygon"></div>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error exercitationem asperiores corrupti amet, sapiente voluptate excepturi facilis distinctio libero quisquam cupiditate quibusdam quis natus vitae facere inventore dolores eos nobis quae nemo incidunt nam cumque repellat minima. Voluptatum eos fuga vitae quam quidem necessitatibus error doloribus, voluptate, deleniti explicabo ipsa beatae. Tenetur quae vero, excepturi, illo et animi similique laborum dolores quasi totam, veritatis ipsum tempora libero natus! Laborum quos minus quaerat. Adipisci, deleniti corrupti! Vitae harum libero necessitatibus magnam aliquam accusamus, vero fuga unde delectus exercitationem, provident quo? Dolores voluptatum, exercitationem deserunt consequatur, accusantium veritatis quaerat modi qui vero esse earum odio, labore nihil harum et voluptatibus ipsum ipsam perspiciatis! Architecto, sunt similique tempore consectetur, nobis possimus eius natus fugit repellat nisi enim, in cupiditate facilis sint deserunt assumenda voluptatibus fuga repudiandae vel minima nemo error qui molestiae magnam. Perspiciatis modi esse quia voluptate dolor non fuga atque illum maiores sint minima similique, dicta culpa eveniet at veritatis vitae ducimus tempora ex, aut soluta, ad autem? Illo, obcaecati facere vel magni dicta, beatae voluptates porro enim ducimus ratione sequi ad reiciendis sapiente exercitationem, aut consequuntur eius maxime. Voluptatibus laudantium inventore saepe minima consequuntur deleniti reiciendis necessitatibus ad culpa ea. Fugit nihil fugiat ipsam, repudiandae culpa distinctio soluta? Laborum nisi quos quisquam vel necessitatibus ipsa ea, eos obcaecati sit veritatis dolores ducimus porro, nostrum recusandae facere aliquam sequi temporibus repellat dolorem voluptas perspiciatis magnam. Aliquam sapiente placeat similique eveniet nisi, quam sunt. Alias quidem, id omnis fuga hic a porro velit reprehenderit tempore sapiente culpa? Quibusdam architecto quaerat voluptatem eligendi eos explicabo voluptatibus, eum necessitatibus voluptates iusto expedita quo natus nobis tempora adipisci laboriosam quod assumenda beatae labore qui asperiores doloremque! Cumque ad laborum enim rem similique distinctio nesciunt velit labore dicta doloribus saepe obcaecati, impedit officiis nulla neque! Qui.</p>
```

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.float-polygon {
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: #00f;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 21.2vmax;
    width: 100vw;
    float: right;
    shape-margin: 1vw;
    shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}

.text {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 5vw;
}
```

Comment: Ну не знаю. Вот скрины:

[хром](https://sun9-75.userapi.com/impf/LkvCj1c7Qo88Bjkr0uKSc_kP1ON1JrV4hFJ3fQ/s90k9j5DkO0.jpg?size=1920x982&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=e75d3bea2dbde4d3eca717f6d48404a2&type=album), 
[firefox](https://sun9-53.userapi.com/impf/jcPgrZ59cX6XbjlSCkYDLhLCDDtQu8LDOJ9IOw/44cU5qOXr2o.jpg?size=1920x1004&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=13d1c32f1988d6c1d0c01159b77a73ed&type=album)

Comment: На отступ влияют ширина и высота блока, но хотелось бы сохранить эти значения, чтобы выглядело одинаково в обоих браузерах

Comment: Да, так можно, но хотелось бы одну и ту же высоту с нормальным отображением

Comment: Увы, ничего не изменилось
https://codepen.io/Ssivenkov/full/zYKJxKp

Comment: Исправил, проблема осталась

Comment: В этом же примере изменил код https://codepen.io/Ssivenkov/pen/zYKJxKp, ничего не изменилось

Comment: https://ibb.co/RBLyFcG   https://ibb.co/KNnqHyN  вот скрины с FF и Хрома

Comment: А если просматривать в full page view ?

Comment: смотрел и так и по другому ...даже с мобилы

Comment: У меня отступ появляется начиная с ширины вьюпорта 1680px. Видимо придётся обходиться без float элемента